# Type int ref but expected int

Tags: compiler-errors, reference, ocaml, typeerror

```
let nombredeCubes = ref 0  in
for i = 1 to 17 do
   nombredeCubes := nombredeCubes + i*i*i
   i := i+1
done;
print_int nombredeCubes;
```

When I try to compile this code, I get the following error:

```
line 3, characters 20-33:
Error: This expression has type int ref
       but an expression was expected of type int
```

Yet I don't understand why. I mean why "for" is expecting an int and not an int ref, is "for" a function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `!` operator to access the value of a ref cell:

```
nombredeCubes := !nombredeCubes + i*i*i
```

You also shouldn't (and won't be allowed to) manually increment `i`. The for construct will do that for you.

**Edit**: It would be much more idiomatic to use recursion instead of mutation and imperative programming to solve this. It would also make the stepping clearer:

```
let nombredeCubes =
  let rec loop acc = function
  | i when i > 0 -> loop (acc + i*i*i) (i-2)
  | _ -> acc
  in loop 0 17
in print_int nombredeCubes
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Yet I don't see how I can get only  the odd number in for loop ?

Comment: That's a different question, but one way would be `for i = 1 to (17/2) do let i' = (i * 2) - 1 in ...`

Comment: @Salutsalut1 I updated the answer with a more idiomatic solution for your problem, which you might find helpful.